# question about the attention calculation in Pytorch seq2seq tutorial: discrepancy with original Badahnau or Luong paper

Tags: nlp, pytorch, attention-model

I am studying the attention recent. I have some doubt about they calculate the attention is Pytorch NLP attention tutorial: https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/seq2seq_translation_tutorial.html.

In the tutorial, they calculate the score or weight using the decoder’s input and decoder's hidden state. However I find out neither Luong or Badahnau do that why. Instead both use the decoder hidden state and the ENCODER output the calculate the weight.
Why Pytorch tutorial do that way?

Comment: But it does. The attention decoder takes an argument named `encoder_output`, on the basis of which they compute atn scores

Comment: @KonstantinosKokos, as far as I know, Luong or Badahnau use DECODER  hidden state and the ENCODER output to calculate the weight, however Pytorch tutorial use only DECODER input and DECODER hidden state to calculate the weight. Check  the class AttnDecoderRNN definition.

Answer (score 0):

The pytorch tutorial seems different to both Luong and Bahdanau attention.